# Error while copying Liferay server from production to test

Tags: liferay, liferay-7

I'm trying to copy Liferay server from production to test server. The production was having some additional properties like load balancing and clustering and other properties. I wanted to make the test server work as the production, So I have copied the database and connected the database. I'm using liferay 7.1.3 ga4. I have done the following:

1. Copied the database
2. Created portal-ext.properties and added the following parameters

   admin.email.from.address=xxx.xx@xx.xx
   admin.email.from.name=admin xxxx
   company.default.web.id=xx.xx
   company.default.name=xx
   company.default.locale=ar_SA
   liferay.home=/u01/liferay-portal-7.1.3-ga4
   setup.wizard.enabled=false
   jdbc.default.driverClassName=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
   jdbc.default.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.10.xx.xx:1525:orcd
   jdbc.default.username=username
   jdbc.default.password=password

I'm currently getting the following issue after trying to start the server. Any hint on how to solve this issue:

```
UT005023: Exception handling request to /home: javax.servlet.ServletException: com.liferay.portal.kernel.exception.NoSuchGroupException: No Group exists with the key {companyId=0, groupKey=Guest}
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:108)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:188)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:96)
        at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:176)
        at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:145)
        at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:92)
        at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:389)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.processFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:65)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:49)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:207)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:112)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:168)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:96)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:168)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:96)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:188)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:96)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:101)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationConstraintHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationConstraintHandler.java:53)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.java:59)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:197)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.HttpContinueReadHandler.handleRequest(HttpContinueReadHandler.java:65)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PathHandler.handleRequest(PathHandler.java:94)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.Host$OptionsHandler.handleRequest(Host.java:337)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.HttpContinueReadHandler.handleRequest(HttpContinueReadHandler.java:65)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.SetHeaderHandler.handleRequest(SetHeaderHandler.java:90)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.SetHeaderHandler.handleRequest(SetHeaderHandler.java:90)
        at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:326)
        at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:812)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.liferay.portal.kernel.exception.NoSuchGroupException: No Group exists with the key {companyId=0, groupKey=Guest}
        at com.liferay.portal.service.persistence.impl.GroupPersistenceImpl.findByC_GK(GroupPersistenceImpl.java:3321)
        at com.liferay.portal.service.impl.GroupLocalServiceImpl.loadGetGroup(GroupLocalServiceImpl.java:2562)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:153)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.transaction.DefaultTransactionExecutor._execute(DefaultTransactionExecutor.java:203)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.transaction.DefaultTransactionExecutor.execute(DefaultTransactionExecutor.java:94)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.transaction.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:113)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:130)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:55)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:130)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:55)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:130)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanAopProxy.invoke(ServiceBeanAopProxy.java:125)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy77.loadGetGroup(Unknown Source)
        at com.liferay.portal.service.impl.GroupLocalServiceImpl.getGroup(GroupLocalServiceImpl.java:1664)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:153)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanAopProxy.invoke(ServiceBeanAopProxy.java:125)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy77.getGroup(Unknown Source)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.service.GroupLocalServiceUtil.getGroup(GroupLocalServiceUtil.java:797)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.service.ServiceContextFactory.getInstance(ServiceContextFactory.java:96)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.absoluteredirects.AbsoluteRedirectsFilter.doFilterTry(AbsoluteRedirectsFilter.java:87)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:186)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:96)
        ... 64 more

08:06:18,175 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-7) UT005022: Exception generating error page /errors/code.jsp: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: JBWEB004038: An exception occurred processing JSP page /errors/code.jsp at line 72

72

69:                     else {
70:                             String validPortalDomain = PortalUtil.getValidPortalDomain(PortalUtil.getDefaultCompanyId(), request.getServerName());
71:
72:                             redirect = PortalUtil.getPortalURL(validPortalDomain, request.getServerPort(), request.isSecure()) + PortalUtil.getPathContext() + PortalUtil.getRelativeHomeURL(request);
73:                     }
74:
75:                     if (!request.isRequestedSessionIdFromCookie()) {




Stacktrace:
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:568)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:471)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:403)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:347)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:119)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:101)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
        at io.undertow.jsp.JspFileHandler.handleRequest(JspFileHandler.java:32)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:274)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchToPath(ServletInitialHandler.java:209)
        at io.undertow.servlet.spec.RequestDispatcherImpl.error(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:480)
        at io.undertow.servlet.spec.RequestDispatcherImpl.error(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:413)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:319)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:197)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.HttpContinueReadHandler.handleRequest(HttpContinueReadHandler.java:65)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PathHandler.handleRequest(PathHandler.java:94)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.Host$OptionsHandler.handleRequest(Host.java:337)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.HttpContinueReadHandler.handleRequest(HttpContinueReadHandler.java:65)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.SetHeaderHandler.handleRequest(SetHeaderHandler.java:90)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.SetHeaderHandler.handleRequest(SetHeaderHandler.java:90)
        at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:326)
        at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:812)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.liferay.portal.util.PortalImpl.getRelativeHomeURL(PortalImpl.java:4837)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.PortalUtil.getRelativeHomeURL(PortalUtil.java:1684)
        at org.apache.jsp.errors.code_jsp._jspService(code_jsp.java:176)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:433)
        ... 44 more
```

Comment: according to your stacktrace, he did not found the Company instance (as it is 0 here). if you cloned you db, you might need to check your `COMPANY` or `VIRTUALHOST` tables, or check the company.default portal properties.

Comment: @AndreAlbert yes I wanted to know how to check it on the database. I want to get the value from the database